# TFS Cutomization using power tools

Tags: tfs-power-tools

Friends 
I have added 3 fields using the Power Tools in TFS->Test case work item. Now is it possible for me to do the below customization?

```
1st field a
2nd field b
3rd field c.
then c equals a plus b.
```

when i enter the values in the fields a & b, field c should be populated with the value a+b. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this isn't possible int he Work Item Definition schema language. If you want the UI to do math based on your work item values, you need to build a server side plugin. There is an open source solution available that handles these kinds of things which you might be able to use for your solution, or you could derive your own solution from that.

See also: [TFS Aggregator project on Codeplex](http://tfsaggregator.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I have followed all the things mentioned in the link. But it just suits there and doing nothing. If you have any idea about TFS Aggregato please let me know.

Comment: Million possibilities... Probably with its own question, possibly at the tfs aggregator discussion area.